Thank you Mathoverflow
I have been bedridden to 6 months because of a car accident and a dream of mine has always been to understand deeply algebraic geometry and advanced math. I have some wiz friends that tell me that that is the most advanced mathematical field. I never graduated from college and now my son wants to be a mathematician because of some movies/shows he has watched. As a result, I have learned a lot by going to the answers on this site and have realized that I actually wanted to be a mathematician deep down. Thank you all for your support.
I don't know what my future is but I can't spend a lot of time now on Mathoverflow anymore because of physical therapy. Thanks for your answers and guidance and hope I can come back in the future.
Apologies if this is not the right place to post this. Feel free to delete this if needed.

Although I am very thankful to MathOverflow too, I think this may not be an appropriate post for the site, which is focused on answering technical questions about mathematics. My condolences on your situation.

Possibly would make more sense as something to post on meta.

Glad to have had you as a community member, Alex, and godspeed on your recovery — hope to see you around here again soon.

I agree that https://meta.mathoverflow.net is a more reasonable place to post such a message.
